# What is the most optimized way to Filter and combine Data from Multiple Collections in MongoDB Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filtering, aggregation

I am trying to filter a data derived by doing `$lookup` on more than 2 collections (in my case 9 collections) and then applying `$and` filters on multiple values from those collections.

Challenges :

1. A normal aggregation pipeline will initially merge all the collections and then apply the filter.
2. This does not feel feasible when the collections have very large datasets.

What should be the most optimized way of doing this kind of aggregation?

### Example :

###### Models :

```js
// User Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
});
const UserModel = model('User', UserSchema);
```

```js
// Posts by User Analytices 
const PostsAnalyticsSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, // Author
    totalPosts: Number,
    lastPostedAt: Date,
});
const PostsAnalyticsModel = model('PostsAnalytics', PostsAnalyticsSchema);
```

```js
// Comments Received by User Analytics
const CommentsAnalyticsSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, // Author
    totalComments: Number,
    lastCommentAt: Date,
});
const CommentsAnalyticsModel = model('CommentsAnalytics', PostsAnalyticsSchema);
```

```js
// Likes Received by User Analytics
const LikesAnalyticsSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, // Author
    totalLikes: Number,
    lastLikeAt: Date,
});
const LikesAnalyticsModel = model('LikesAnalytics', LikesAnalyticsSchema);
```

###### Single Aggregation Query :

```js
const getUsersData = async () => {
    const data = await UserModel.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'postsanalytics',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'user',
                as: 'postsAnalytics'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$postsAnalytics',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'commentsanalytics',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'user',
                as: 'commentsAnalytics'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$commentsAnalytics',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'likesanalytics',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'user',
                as: 'likesAnalytics'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$likesAnalytics',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                // any kind of Filteration on the values derived from 4 collections
                'postsAnalytics.totalPosts': { $gt: 0 },
                'postsAnalytics.lastPostedAt': { $gt: new Date('2023-01-01') },
                'commentsAnalytics.totalComments': { $gt: 10, $lt: 20 },
                'likesAnalytics.totalLikes': { $eq: 10 },
            }
        }
    ])
};
```

My concern is that before the `$match` runs, MongoDB combines all 4 collections' data in mempry and then queries the results (most probably without any help from individual collection's indexes).

###### One solution I have in mind is as below :

```js
const getUsersData = async () => {
    const postsIds = await PostsAnalyticsModel.distinct('user', {
        'postsAnalytics.totalPosts': { $gt: 0 },
        'postsAnalytics.lastPostedAt': { $gt: new Date('2023-01-01') },
    });
    const commentsIds = await CommentsAnalyticsModel.distinct('user', {
        'commentsAnalytics.totalComments': { $gt: 10, $lt: 20 },
    });
    const likesIds = await LikesAnalyticsModel.distinct('user', {
        'likesAnalytics.totalLikes': { $eq: 10 },
    });
    const data = await UserModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: {
                    $in: [...postsIds, ...commentsIds, ...likesIds]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'postsanalytics',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'user',
                as: 'postsAnalytics'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$postsAnalytics',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'commentsanalytics',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'user',
                as: 'commentsAnalytics'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$commentsAnalytics',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'likesanalytics',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'user',
                as: 'likesAnalytics'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$likesAnalytics',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
    ]);

};
```

I also tried implementing GraphQL with Apollo Server and GraphQL Compose but could not workout a possible solution.

Comment: 9 collections look like a very poor data design. NoSQL databases like MongoDB are not optimized for joins (some NoSQL database even do not support joins at all)., You may review your data model.

Comment: You could use `"$match"` in a `"$lookup"` `"pipeline"` to limit what is returned from each `"$lookup"` rather than waiting to `"$match"` later.